# How to pickle QPixmap object dict in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpixmap

I want to pickle QPixmap object dict in Python 3

For example,

```
ImageQpixmapDict = {}
ImageQpixmapDict['XXX'] = QPixmap()
```

In this situation, I want to pickle ImageQpixmapDict variable

like

```
pickle.dump(ImageQpixmapDict, 'filePath')
```

I tried to pickle QPixmap object by using QSettings, but it doesn't work.

But as you know, QPixmap object couldn't be pickled. So, How can I solve this problem.

Comment: `QPixmap` has a `save` method, can you not use that?

Comment: Iain Shelvington  No, I want to save not Img file but binary data (include variable info, like pickle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some Qt classes are pickable (see [the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pickle.html)) and among them there is no QPixmap so a solution is to create a derived class that implements that logic:

```
import pickle
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui


class Pickable_QPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap):
    def __reduce__(self):
        return type(self), (), self.__getstate__()

    def __getstate__(self):
        ba = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(ba, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        stream << self
        return ba

    def __setstate__(self, ba):
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(ba, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        stream >> self


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    # create QPixmap
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor("red"))

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:

        image_dict = dict()
        image_dict["XXX"] = Pickable_QPixmap(
            pixmap
        )  # convert QPixmap to Pickable_QPixmap
        pickle.dump(image_dict, f)

    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        image_dict = pickle.load(f)
        pixmap = image_dict["XXX"]

        qpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pixmap)  # convert Pickable_QPixmap to QPixmap

        assert qpixmap.size() == pixmap.size() == QtCore.QSize(100, 100)
        assert qpixmap.toImage() == pixmap.toImage()
```