# PIL Image to QImage crash and distortion

Tags: pyqt, python-imaging-library, qimage

I am using Pillow to load an image in the background and pass it to the foreground of my PyQt app as bytes, to then convert it to a QImage to display in the GUI. The majority of the time this works great, however it seems that if my image is not divisible by 2 in either dimension then the QImage is distorted or the app crashes. I made a test of this by loading a jpeg which was 341x512 and it came out black and white and with horizontal stripes, and then just by resizing it in photoshop to 340x512 it loaded perfectly. I then resized it to 339x512 and it came out distorted again.

This clearly has something to do with `image.tobyes()` interacting poorly with the QImage constructor. I am just guessing that the bytes are somehow getting rounded, or something like that? I'm really not sure what the issue is, I assume bytes are just bytes but clearly that is wrong.

How can I fix this? What is QImage expecting that PIL is not providing? Here's a sample script:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageQt

im = Image.open('')
im.convert('RGB')
bytes = im.tobytes('raw', 'RGB')


# at this point in my app the bytes get sent back to the main process from a sub-process.


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
im = Image.frombytes('RGB', im.size, bytes) # <- 'bytes' comes in from a Manager
label.setPixmap(ImageQt.toqpixmap(im))
label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use  `qimage = ImageQt(im).copy()`, add `from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt` after import PyQt5

Comment: @eyllanesc I do need to convert it to bytes though so that I can pickle it. Or do you do that before you covert it to bytes?

Comment: I do not understand what you are talking about, nothing of what you indicate is in your post so your explanation is not clear. If you want to make QImage (or QPixmap) pickable you could use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401768/6622587.